# How do I check if a table exists?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, node-postgres

In db/index.js:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg'); //node-postgres
const pool = new Pool;

module.exports = {
    query: (text, params, callback) => {
        return pool.query(text,params,callback);
    }
};
```

In my main.js:

```
const db = require('./db/index');

    db.query('SELECT count(*) from pg_class where relname ="session" and relkind="r"', (err, res) => {
        if (err) {
          //TODO: What to do if there is an error?
        }
        console.log(res);
    });
```

The output is:

> undefined

How do I check if the table with name "session" exists or not ? How do I know my query even works ?

EDIT: This is not a duplicate of the above questions, because my question has to do with the Node.js javascript code. Not the SQL! I just want to know what to look for in the res object, since it seems to be undefined...

Comment: Holler her name, and if answered - the table is there.

Comment: Suggest you edit the title as it's misleading.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can check below code;

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1
   FROM   information_schema.tables 
   WHERE  table_schema = 'schema_name'
   AND    table_name = 'table_name'
   );
```

or

```
SELECT EXISTS (
   SELECT 1 
   FROM   pg_catalog.pg_class c
   JOIN   pg_catalog.pg_namespace n ON n.oid = c.relnamespace
   WHERE  n.nspname = 'schema_name'
   AND    c.relname = 'table_name'
   );
```

or

```
SELECT 'schema_name.table_name'::regclass
```

or

```
SELECT to_regclass('schema_name.table_name');
```

If not exist this query returns null

Comment: How will I check the response in the node.js code ? And how do I know what the schema name is ? All I did was create a table..